# Select from insert

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to select from an insert statement?  For example:

```
SELECT id FROM (INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2));
```

Where `id` is an autoincrementing primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in such way, because `INSERT` doesn't return virtual table for `SELECT`. However you could get id's actual value using [`currval(regclass)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) sequence function as:

```
SELECT currval('yourTableName_id_seq'::regclass);
 currval 
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

**EDIT:**

Use [`RETURNING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) (available since PostgreSQL 8.2):

```
INSERT INTO yourTableName (col1, col2) VALUES ('aaa', 'bbb') RETURNING id;
 id 
----
  2
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id IS NULL;

"id" has to be an auto_increment column to make it work.
It will return the last_insert_id just as last_insert_id() is expected to do.

example:
mysql> INSERT INTO orders (customer_cust_id, orderdatetime, message, taxrate, shippingprice)
-> SELECT '1', NOW(), null, taxrate, shippingprice FROM customer
-> WHERE cust_id='1';"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I'm looking for a way to grab the ID the moment it's created, as it could be possible that another insert happens between the insert and the select, so the most recent entry is not the one I want... and having just said that, I'm now going to look at transactions